# How to add SVG as an image+xml in d3 version 4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an svg having objects inside it which can be read off as xml. I am not able to use d3.xml function in version 4 so I am having problem in reading the objects inside the svg. At the moment I have added the svg like this:

```
var sketchSVG = d3.select("#sketch4").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(sketchZoom.on("zoom", sketchZoomCallback))
    .append("g");

sketchSVG.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "img/sketch_all_in_components_web.svg")
    .attr("width", 560)
    .attr("height", 560)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -78);
```

The problem here is that I can only see the svg as an image on the html page as if there are no objects inside. I want to read those objects as well which can only be done if I add the svg as image+xml. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you load a SVG as an image, you do not have access to its DOM, period. Why are you not able to use d3.xml()? It is still part of d3.v4 and available seperately as https://github.com/d3/d3-request. It only will be deprecated for d3.v5 (currently at RC3).

Comment: @ccprog Actually I want to add a zoom functionality on it. So I guess d3.zoom does not work with d3.xml and instead i have to use d3.behavior.zoom (which is not working incase of version 4). Thats why I had to shift from d3.xml to what i am doing now. Is there a way out to it? Is there a way to make d3.zoom workable with d3.xml in version 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you retrieve a SVG file via `d3.request`, the `xhr.responseXML` property is a document instance. You can select the root `<svg>` and append it directly.

Attach the zoom behavior to an outer svg as above and append the retrieved svg as its child:

```
var sketchZoom = d3.zoom();
var sketchSVG = d3.select("#sketch4").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(sketchZoom.on("zoom", sketchZoomCallback));

function responseCallback (xhr) {
    sketchSVG.append(function () {
            return xhr.responseXML.querySelector('svg');
        }).attr("width", 560)
        .attr("height", 560)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", -78);
}

d3.request("img/sketch_all_in_components_web.svg")
    .mimeType("image/svg+xml")
    .response(responseCallback)
    .get();
```

Comment: Hi ccprog! I appreciate your help. I have implemented what you suggested above but the problem is that I am not able to see the image inside the div at all. It seems like d3.request is not working. Do you know where could be the problem?

Comment: oopsie - I just realised I misread the d3.request doc. You have to explicitely sent the request with .get(). See edit.